# Android: what is the equivalent for my own App resource instead android.resource://system/

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to use my own resource (drawable) instead of this:

```
"android.resource://system/com.android.internal.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history"
```

To : android.resource://XXXX/R.drawable.ic_my_icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android.resource://com.example.myapp/drawable/ic_my_icon`, bearing in mind that not everything in an Android device will support the `android.resource` scheme.

See [the documentation for `openAssetFileDescriptor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) for more about this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Put your drawable.xml in a res/drawable folder and use this:

```
R.drawable.your_drawable_name
```